# Adding more apps to running gevent pywsgi.WSGIServer

Tags: python, wsgi, gevent

I have an application that looks like this:

```
application = DirectoryApp(
                           'app/static',
                           index_page='index.html',
                           hide_index_with_redirect=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = get_config()

    from gevent import pywsgi
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer((config['host'], config['port']), application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Is it possible to add another app to the stack using code after the server has started? What I want is to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
# Create new application class
class AnotherController((object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from webob import Request, Response
        req = Request(environ)

        if req.method == 'GET' and req.path_info.startswith('/anothercontroller'):
            res = Response(
                body='Hello World, Another Controller!',
                status=200,
                content_type='text/plain'
            )

            return res(environ, start_response)

        return self.app(environ, start_response)

def add_application():
    global application
    application = AnotherController(application)

# Add the application to the stack after the fact it is already running
add_application()
```

The problem is that by doing this it never goes in to the `__call__` of the new application class that I put on top of the application stack.

To me it seems like I'm not affecting the stack that the server is actually using...

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this. WSGI is designed to run one app at a time. There are probably numerous other ways of implementing what you want, and if you're using a framework like Django, Pyramid, or Flask, there are other patterns for this (like blueprints for Flask).

Answer (score -1):

You could use use paste's cascade to load up multiple wsgi apps:
http://pythonpaste.org/modules/cascade.html

Here's an example of code using it with gevent.pywsgi:

```
def http_server():
    static_app = paste.urlparser.StaticURLParser(
        os.path.join(twit.__path__[0], "static"))
    apps = paste.cascade.Cascade([static_app, search.app])
    http_server = gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer(
        ('', 8000), apps)
    http_server.start()
```

Comment: It's not really what I'm asking for... please read the qeuestion again.